# img src & jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, button, attributes, src

I have an image, and using jQuery I've turned it into a button.
The so called button has two states: regular and pushed.

Using jQuery I detect a "mousedown" and "mouseup" and replace the "src" attribute, like so:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   ;//DO SOMETHING HERE WHEN PRESSED
});
$("#btn").mousedown(function() {
   $(this).attr({ src: regular.png });
});
$("#btn").mouseup(function() {
   $(this).attr({ src : pushed.png });
});
```

While testing this offline it works great! But today I noticed that when the images are stored on the server it loads the images over and over and over again with every attribute change.

How can avoid this load issue and make all the images load only once from the server?

Also, if there is a better to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the user agent, not the server.

Comment: What do you mean by user agent? The browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a single image containing both button states. Then, dynamically change the position of the background image on mouseout/mouseover:

```
<style type="text/css">

 .button_normal {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-image: url(merged_button_bg.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: solid black 1px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .button_over {
  background-position: -50px;
 }

</style>

<div class="button_normal"></div>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button_normal').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).addClass('button_over');
  });
  $('.button_normal').mouseout(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('button_over');
  });
 });

</script>
```

This example assumes a target image of 50px square and `merged_button_bg.png` is 100px by 50px.

Comment: Can I do this with <span> ? Because the <div> doesn't like to stay on the same line with other divs :/

Comment: You can add a `float: left` rule to the `.button_normal` class to get the divs to align side-by-side

Comment: Or display: block; to <span> :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing the src attribute, you could use a span or div to show the image (via a background image) and create two CSS classes, one for each image. Then you can just toggle the element's CSS class to switch buttons.

Comment: +1. Better again, using css sprites will lower the count of requests. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: This is one of the most elegant solutions for this. Like Alex recommends, I'd use a CSS sprite like in the example posted by pygorex1.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Preload](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Preload) plugin?

Update:  Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough, I thought it was a rollover requirement.  A more general preload script is [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript).

Incidentally, I agree that CSS sprites are the better solution **if** they are appropriate to the situation, i.e. if you have complete control over the images themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure Preload will solve the issue here.
For example:
The initial state is "regular". Once I hold the button it loads from the server the "pushed" image. When I release the button it loads the "regular" image, again! And so on.
The browsers are just loading the same images over and over again...